# Makefile error raspberry-pi 3

Tags: c++, makefile, raspbian, raspberry-pi3, codelite

I have an issue with Codelite compilation, running on raspbian jessie - these are the (known) steps I have taken to produce it.

First I installed Codelite with `apt-get install Codelite`, then produced a c++ project.

When running build project I get the error:

```
/bin/sh -c ' -j 4 -e -f  Makefile'
/bin/sh: 1: -j: not found
0 errors, 0 warnings
```

I note that this error has been found and corrected previously, through running a different version of Codelite from 6.1.1 (that which apt-get installs). I therefore found the updated version of armhf .deb codelite from the rasbian archive with gdebi-gtk. However the updated version (9.1.1) produces the following error (install attempt with the graphical debian):

```
Error: Dependency is not satisfiable: libclang 1-3.8 (>=3.2)
```

I do not understand why the package manager cannot update these packages - do they not exist for the pi? I ran the manager as root, so I do not think it is a permissions issue.

**EDIT 1:**

Thank you for that Fabre. My Enviromental Variables file now looks like this:

```
CodeLiteDir=/usr/share/codelite
export MAKE=make
```

I still get the same error however.

Comment: try to set `MAKE` env variable: `export MAKE=make`

Comment: Fabre, I am not sure if edit produce notifications, so please do not think me to be impatient. In case of otherwise however, please be kind enough to see my edit above.

Comment: sorry, that was just a shot in the dark. Can you post the contents of the script you're running (which gives you the error)

Comment: Thank you - I have now figured out the problem: my project settings were overwriding my global settings,resulting in the wrong compiler being used.